# Javascript conflict with WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, geolocation

I got this geolocation working but if I put it in WordPress it stops working.
What's wrong with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/spzg5oL8/3/

```
$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    //$("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
    document.getElementsByClassName(response.country_code)[0].style.display = "block";
}, "jsonp");
```

Comment: What do you mean it "stops working"? Do you see any errors in your console? (hit F12 to view the console)

Comment: the orange box will only show for users in us and ca, and it working fine on jsfiddle i can see the orange box and im in the us, but after i take that put that in the footer template of my site which is using wordpress i dont see that orange box, i looked in the console dont see any js errors

Comment: Again, do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: no i dont see any errors in console at all

Answer (score 2):

This will not work in WordPress for one reason (for sure), and another reason (potentially):

First, you cannot use the `$` for jQuery in WordPress.  WordPress loads jQuery in "no-conflict" mode, which means you have to use `jQuery`, OR wrap this in a document ready method to "inject" the `$`:

```
 jQuery(function($) {
    $.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
        $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
        //$("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
        // Why don't you use jQuery here, for simplicity?
        // $('.' + response.country_code).style('display', 'block');
        document.getElementsByClassName(response.country_code)[0].style.display = "block";
    }, "jsonp");
});
```

Second, you have to be sure that jQuery is **loaded** on your WordPress site.  Whatever you do, do **not** just hard-code a link to jQuery in the header of the site, but rather, in the `functions.php` file for the theme (or plugin) add the below php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts');

function load_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: thanks cale_b,  also another thing the site is on ssl so the "http://freegeoip.net/json/" was blocked, i updated the script and the functions.php like you suggested now its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @cale_b said, you can see the call to `jQuery.noConflict();` as the last line of Wordpress's jQuery file:

```
/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
```

I haven't found anything explicitly in the documentation, but seeing it in the code helps to know what's happening.